# What should be my return type for this function?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, c#-4.0, types, lambda

I have the following function:

```
public void Test(IDataContext context)
{
        return (From c In context.Table<DalLinq.Claim>()
                Join cli In context.Table<DalLinq.ClaimLineItem>() On cli.ClaimId Equals c.ClaimId
                Join ri In context.Table<DalLinq.ReceiptItem>() On ri.ReceiptItemId Equals cli.ReceiptItemId
                Join r In context.Table<DalLinq.Receipt>() On r.ReceiptId Equals ri.ReceiptId
                Select c, cli, ri, r)
}
```

I had this before as a variable in a function but I need it in multiple places now so I am placing this in a function but I have no idea what my return type should be. In the example it shows void but that is because I don't know what to put.

Given the following / working code in the return statement, what should this return type be?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I need it as a non executed format so I can't ToList it or create custom objects for it as it will be filtered by which ever class is calling this method.

Comment: Your *EDIT* explanation is hardly inderstandable. Return type of methods must always be of some exact type. You should not return anonymous types. Could you at least provide some code of how you'd like to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can create a class that represents your methods result.

#### Sample

```
public class MyReturnClass 
{
    DalLinq.Claim Claim { get; set; }
    DalLinq.ClaimLineItem ClaimLineItem { get; set; }
    DalLinq.ReceiptItem ReceiptItem { get; set; }
    DalLinq.Receipt Receipt { get; set; }
}

public MyReturnClass Test(IDataContext context)
{
        return (From c In context.Table<DalLinq.Claim>()
                Join cli In context.Table<DalLinq.ClaimLineItem>() On cli.ClaimId Equals c.ClaimId
                Join ri In context.Table<DalLinq.ReceiptItem>() On ri.ReceiptItemId Equals cli.ReceiptItemId
                Join r In context.Table<DalLinq.Receipt>() On r.ReceiptId Equals ri.ReceiptId
                Select new MyReturnClass { Claim = c, ClaimLineItem = cli, ReceiptItem = ri, Receipt = r }).First();
}
```

Comment: I need it as a non executed format because it gets filtered after this method call.

Comment: What you mean ? I dont understand.

Comment: @dknaack I think he means he wants an `IQueryable`

Comment: Lanvinski is right. I modified it a bit to get what I want though and it worked, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I assume that `context.Table<T>()` returns an `IQueryable<T>`, if that's the case you could write this:

```
public static class IDataContextExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> MyFilter<T>(this IDataContext context, Func<Claim, ClaimLineItem, ReceiptItem, Receipt, T> resultor)
    {
        return from c fn context.Table<DalLinq.Claim>()
            join cli in context.Table<DalLinq.ClaimLineItem>() on cli.ClaimId equals c.ClaimId
            join ri in context.Table<DalLinq.ReceiptItem>() on ri.ReceiptItemId equals cli.ReceiptItemId
            join r in context.Table<DalLinq.Receipt>() on r.ReceiptId equals ri.ReceiptId
            select resultor(c, cli, ri, r);
    }  
}
```

this way you do not need a 'dto' class, and you would call this method like this:

```
var data = myContext.MyFilter((c, cli, ri, r) => new 
                                                 { 
                                                     Claim = c, 
                                                     ClaimLineItem = cli, 
                                                     ReceiptItem = ri, 
                                                     Receipt = r 
                                                 }).ToList();
```

the result would be an `IEnumerable<X>`, where `X` is the anonymous type passed to `MyFilter`.

Disclaimer: untested code, just showing an idea.